# height attribute cause stopped script

Tags: javascript, php, extjs4

I am using a Panel to show the scrollable grid. My code is

```
var resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
height:140,
items: companyView,
renderTo: 'addTable'+i,
layout: 'fit'
});

var checkbox = new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel();
companyView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title:'',
    selModel: checkbox,
    id:'companylist'+i,
    store: store1,
    multiSelect: true,
    viewConfig: { emptyText: 'No data to display'},
    columns:[
                {header: 'Type', width: 80, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'type',
                renderer: sample},
                {header: '%', width: 30, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'per'},
                {header: 'Name', width: 30, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'name',renderer:functOwnerNameCmp},
                {header: 'O.%', width: 50, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'owner'},
                {header: 'Role', width: 30, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'role'},
                {header: 'Gender', width: 50, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'gender'}
            ],
    tbar  : [
                {
                    text: 'Delete Selected',
                    margins: '0 0 0 290',
                    handler: function() 
                    {
                        rowsSelected = companyView.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                        if(rowsSelected.length==0) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert(' ', 'Please select one record');
                        } else {
                            Ext.MessageBox.confirm(' ', 'Are you sure you want to remove Person?',confirmRemoveAffCmpRec);
                    }
                }
            }    
            ]
        });
```

If I don't use the height attribute, the script is ok but if I use height in this attribute the script gets stopped and the message is shown by the browser for eg in Mozilla-
**Unresponsive Script**
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Hi, you mean if you put `height:140` it causes Unresponsive script, as you have used above?

Comment: @vaibhavmande: yes. I have to use it as because scrollable grid can't be achieved without it.

Comment: it may depend on what is in `companyView`, provide this extra information - what is/are the inner panel(s)?

Comment: @zamnuts: companyView is a grid in which data is loaded with not more than 4 or 5 rows..

Comment: Apart from companyView there is nothing there which will give rise to and unresponsive script.

Comment: @AdityaVijay need to see the code for `Ext.grid.Panel` too please. Don't need the `Ext.data.Store`. Also something from the `addTableN` might be helpful to see the layout dependencies and influences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is Ok, I just needed to specify width also whenever I used the height attribute.